# git-stash is moving my master branch

Tags: git, git-stash

I'm trying to switch from a feature branch to master without losing my changes, and so I'm trying to `git stash` and then switch to master, but master is moving to my feature branch. Basically:

```
<feature*> $ git status
# On branch feature
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   hay.md
<feature*> $ git rev-parse --short HEAD
737b183 
<feature*> $ git rev-parse --short master
109b5f7 # This happens to be 4 commits ago
<feature*> $ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on feature: 737b183 Some commit
HEAD is now at 737b183 Some commit
<feature> $ git rev-parse --short HEAD
737b183 
<feature> $ git rev-parse --short master
737b183 # WAT??!!!
```

Am I misunderstanding git-stash? Or maybe git as a whole? <del>Or do I misunderstand the nature of the correspondence of perception and reality?</del>

**Update**
I just discovered it does the same thing in the case of a `git reset`.

```
<feature*> $ git status
# On branch feature
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   hay.md
<feature*> $ git rev-parse --short HEAD
737b183 
<feature*> $ git rev-parse --short master
109b5f7
<feature*> $ git reset --hard HEAD
HEAD is now at 737b183 Some commit
<feature> $ git rev-parse --short HEAD
737b183 
<feature> $ git rev-parse --short master
737b183 # Hm....
```

**Another Update**

It's only happening in one "instance" of the repo (I don't know the right git vocabulary), so I imagine there is something wonky in `.git/`. A bandaid solution is to delete the repo and clone it from the remote again, but I'd kind of like to know *why* it's happening.

**Some more stuff**

```
‹master› » git checkout feature
Switched to branch 'feature'
Your branch is ahead of 'master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
‹feature› » echo "Hay" >> hay.md
‹feature*› » cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/feature
‹feature*› » cat .git/refs/heads/master
93d9d14b0f298ed28cc1520905768281f32d0929
‹feature*› » cat .git/refs/heads/feature
51410c5dcd679b8cf57a7dce2d17be7bbd121923
‹feature*› » git stash
‹feature› » cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/feature
‹feature› » cat .git/refs/heads/master
51410c5dcd679b8cf57a7dce2d17be7bbd121923
‹feature› » cat .git/refs/heads/feature
51410c5dcd679b8cf57a7dce2d17be7bbd121923
```

Comment: Does it turn back when you unstash your changes? Does it persist on repeating this actions? Does it persist if you stash it in a named stash? Wat indeed.

Comment: @golergka It persists in both cases. Also see edit above.

Comment: You might try looking at the output of `git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate` before and after the stash. It might make it easier to get a broader overview of what changes are (or are not) being applied to your history.

Comment: Does it happen if you check out the same repository in other location? Or on other machine? May be there's something with your global git configuration.

Comment: @chepner I'm using `tig` for the same purpose, and basically it's showing the ref for the master branch jumping up to the HEAD of the feature branch, with no other changes to history occurring.

Comment: Is there something weird in `.git/refs/heads/master` and/or `.git/packed-refs`?  Any bizarre disk / file system errors?

Comment: @golergka Thanks for the suggestion. It doesn't happen on another computer, or in another location, so it's just this repo.

Comment: @torek, nothing weird, all the refs are correct (except that they mysteriously move)

Comment: @Jake then it definitely must be a repo configuration problem. I think you can localize it pretty easy if you identify how your existing repo configuration is different from a repo freshly checked out from remote. Just do `diff` on configuration files. Please post the answer if you find it, I'm really curious about it.

Comment: @Jake what do you mean *correct*?  Can you show the output of `cat .git/HEAD`, `cat .git/refs/heads/master` and `cat .git/refs/heads/feature`?  Don't use `rev-parse`, it's peeling the refs.

Comment: Is .git/refs/heads/master not a symbolic link? In your working directory, is there any file which has same inode (=hardlinked to) with .git/refs/head/master?

Comment: @EdwardThomson I just updated the question with results

Comment: @npcode No, it's not a symbolic link, but it's not a symbolic link in any of my git repos. And the only file in my working directory with that inode is .git/refs/head/master

Comment: The easiest way is to checkout git.git project, add -x to the top line in git-stash.sh and run it instead. You will have the full log of what is happening.

Comment: @golergka there were an awful lot of differences when I diffed, too many for me to make sense of, but nothing that seemed illogical. It's a proprietary project, so I can't really post any details just in case, but mostly .git/log and .git/objects differ (which makes sense) and some of the refs in .git/packed-refs differ.

Comment: @Jake This is curious indeed.  I would be interested to see the differences between `.git/packed-refs` and the `.git/refs` folders as well.

Comment: Check `.git/config` and `~/.gitconfig` for defined aliases. Maybe someone made you a joke.

Comment: @skalee I wish it were that simple/devious. Unfortunately not, though.

Comment: Does it happen with detached HEAD, too? What happens if you `git branch -D master` and then `git checkout master`? (You probably already have a backup of the repository set up.)

Comment: @michas Yes, I do in fact have a backup. It does *not* happen with detached HEAD. It does happen after deleted master. Weird.

Comment: Well, it's interesting cause, what happens if you just store a patch with `git diff > 1.diff` (instead of stashing), then `git reset --hard`, and `git checkout master` where the HEAD is?

Comment: you may diff the `.git` folder with GNU diff (like `diff -NBPbpur .git /other/.git`), then show us diff. But make sure that HEADs in the both .gits are the same.

Comment: Another thing interesting to look at is `git show --decorate --format=fuller refs/stash`, `cat .git/refs/stash` and `tail .git/logs/refs/stash`. Did you strip the output of `git stash`? Which version of git are you using?

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it's sort of a time sink and there are too many variables. I never did figure out, but it's isolated to a single copy of the repo, so it became corrupted somewhere apparently and it doesn't seem worth the time to continue to investigate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I once noticed a similar behavior when I accidentally created both a branch and a tag called `foo` and git internally accessed a commit by name and took the wrong one.

Did you maybe accidentally create a tag called `master` or anything like that?

Also `git reflog` should show what is going on.

Comment: `git reflog` doesn't actually show anything in this case (I guess stashes don't show up in reflog?).

Comment: @Jake stashes actually are saved only in a reflog (apart from the most recent stash). See `git reflog refs/stash`